# Save Json file contents to CSV file in python/pandas

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests, request-headers

How to get the "data" information into a csv table as shown at the end (and also, the right 'headers' so that the source server doesn't throw me off thinking I am scraping)?  The code I wrote so far is as below.

```
import requests, json

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
data_json = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/foSecStockWatch.json', headers=headers)
print(data_json)

file = open('make_csv', 'w')
file.write(str(data_json))
file.close()
```

But as the output I receive is as follows:

```
<Response [200]>
```

and even the exported/saved file shows the same.

Here is the expected output table that I am trying to achieve:

```
Symbol,Open,High,Low,Last Traded Price,Change,%Change,Traded Volume(lacs),Traded Value(crs),52 Week High,52 Week Low,365 Days % Change,30 Days % Change
"LUPIN","582.45","665.90","578.00","662.00","82.95","14.33","64.93","411.13","884.00","504.75","-14.88","5.11"
"APOLLOHOSP","1,094.20","1,239.45","1,088.05","1,195.00","106.15","9.75","23.97","280.36","1,813.55","1,047.05","-4.80","-30.87"
"SUNPHARMA","343.95","389.80","340.00","376.45","32.90","9.58","285.51","1,055.40","483.90","312.00","-19.85","1.88"
"CIPLA","425.00","454.70","416.25","448.00","34.25","8.28","179.07","793.22","586.00","355.30","-14.28","11.46"
"CESC","393.00","429.80","386.25","420.00","26.85","6.83","9.30","38.63","851.70","365.25","-42.19","-34.53"
"TORNTPHARM","1,979.00","2,113.00","1,950.00","2,090.00","131.00","6.69","10.13","208.87","2,287.25","1,452.00","10.56","-1.75"
"ITC","167.90","182.75","167.00","177.50","11.10","6.67","628.68","1,100.88","310.00","134.60","-40.42","-9.11"
"OIL","82.25","85.60","80.25","84.50","5.25","6.62","27.05","22.39","189.70","63.50","-53.95","-16.91"
..........
..........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    x = []
    for item in r['data']:
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([item])
        x.append(df)
    new = pd.concat(x, ignore_index=True)
    print(new)
    new.to_csv("Data.csv")


main("https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/foSecStockWatch.json")
```

Output: [view online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/b6601be5aa86b27e05e7f822a67534c8/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Dear αԋɱҽԃ, thank you for the solution there.. but the csv file contains the following too..("noChg,adv,dec,data,totQty,totQtyMil,totValMil,time,totVal
1,43,100,"....")  Data doesn't seem to be formated as a plain csv, but looks exactly like json..is it possible to only have data with headers like symbol,open,high.... rather than the exact data of the json file pls.. it would be very kind of you to help... thank you

Comment: Dear αԋɱҽԃ, thanks again.. and I received an error pls.. < Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 20, in <module>
    main("https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/foSecStockWatch.json")
  File "tester.py", line 13, in main
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item, index='orient')
TypeError: from_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index' >>   I am sorry I am unsure where the error is... kindly guide me further on this..

Comment: @Lokkii9 code updated. sorry i was typing from mobile.

Comment: Thank you so very much  αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη... really perfect code... appreciate it... :)